# SQL Server with EF Core Net Topology Suite Within Query Not Returning Correct Results

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, ef-core-2.2, nettopologysuite

I have a Google Map that I'm getting the bounds from, and sending those to the server to get a list of markers.

Here's an example set of parameters passed up:

```
neLat   60.11131083608817
neLng   -74.22879847513246
swLat   47.2231665957533
swLng   -157.85672816263252
```

For a sanity check I put them in here, and the box is what I'd expect:

http://bboxfinder.com/#47.223167,-157.856728,60.111311,-74.228798

Here's how I use them in the query:

```
var points = new[]
{
    new Coordinate(neLng.Value, neLat.Value), // TR
    new Coordinate(neLng.Value, swLat.Value), // BR
    new Coordinate(swLng.Value, swLat.Value), // BL
    new Coordinate(swLng.Value, neLat.Value), // TL
    new Coordinate(neLng.Value, neLat.Value), // TR
};

var fact = NtsGeometryServices.Instance.CreateGeometryFactory(srid: 4326);
var poly = fact.CreatePolygon(points).Normalized().Reverse();
query = query.Where(x => x.Location.Within(poly));
```

This doesn't return any results (despite there being several locations that should show up), but it does if I zoom in **or** out, which doesn't make sense. They will also re-appear if I pan the box over slightly.

When the markers are on the map, they are at the correct spots.

It's almost like SQL Server's polygon is shifted up in the center - I can see them still being returned in the results when I've moved the bounding box downwards.